# Error Checking Option Boxes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build in an error checking for two option boxes I have:

```
projectOptionbox
implementOptionbox
```

This is the current code I have right now for error checking a couple of other things, just unsure as to what kind of code is necessary for option boxes:

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.initiativeCombobox, "Please select an Initiative") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select an Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.hoursTextbox, "Please enter the amount of Monthly Hours") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.peopleTextbox, "Please enter the amount of People on the Project") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2, "Please select Project Length") Then Exit Function

    CheckInputs = True
End Function

Private Function CountSelectedListBoxItems(lb As MSForms.ListBox) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then CountSelectedListBoxItems = CountSelectedListBoxItems + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox"
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If errMsg = "" Then Exit Function
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I need to build in error checking for option boxes and I'm unsure what is the best way to work it into this macro. At the moment, there is no error checking for option boxes

Comment: Meaning like an `On Error GoTo <line>` call?

Comment: Yeah, so like if none of the option boxes are checked, then a message box would pop up saying "Select if the project is Project Work or Implementation." Just building in a code similar to what I have above, currently that code error checks everything else in my form besides the option boxes.

Comment: do you mean Option Button or a check box?

Comment: both of those default to `False` so there is no need to error check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered from the post, it sounds like you want to develop a method of confirming that an `OptionButton` within a group has been selected. (Not looking for an application error per se, but rather a violation of your business logic).

This is a bit more complicated than the checks on the other controls because the other controls are standalone. There are two options. (1) Since the `OptionButton` control doesn't actually support a null state, you can set a default option on the Form's `Initialization`. Then, irrespective of what the user does, one of the options will always be selected.

The other option is to use the `GroupName` property of the `OptionButtons` to put buttons into a group. (When optionbuttons are in a group, this ensures that one of them is selected). Next, you can loop through all of the controls looking for `OptionButtons` of the same `GroupName`, then check if at least one of them is selected. A helper function such as the one below should do the trick:

```
Private Function OptionBoxGroupHasASelection(inputControl As MSForms.Control) As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim sGroup As String
    Dim bOutput As Boolean

    If TypeName(inputControl) <> "OptionButton" Then
        OptionBoxGroupHasASelection = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If inputControl.Value = True Then
        OptionBoxGroupHasASelection = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    sGroup = inputControl.GroupName
    bOutput = False

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If ctrl.GroupName = sGroup Then
                If ctrl.Value = True Then
                    bOutput = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    OptionBoxGroupHasASelection = bOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I just set the value to true on form initialization, probably saves me some work. Didn't even think about that, you're a life saver.

Comment: @adrenom No worries. One thing to keep in mind is that the `OptionButton` control actually does have a `TripleState` property (which is the property that allows for True, False, and Null values) but it's currently disabled in VBA. If this feature is ever actually enabled in the future, you may be obligated to use the more difficult option.